# How to specify a config file with path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to setup one web.config file for my solution. How do I specify the path of the config file I am using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can specify new app setting in your web.config file.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="LoggingDir" value="C:\\Logs\\"/>
  <add key="environment" value="test"/>
  <add key="smtp.server" value="incoming.ABank.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

And you can access in your code by

```
private static String logDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LoggingDir"].ToString();
private static String MailServer= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp.server"].ToString();
```

I prefer all my app or environmental settings in a separate file when I have lot of them. You can do that by

```
<appSettings configSource="env\ApplicationSettings.config"/>
```

and then write above `<appSettings> </appSettings>` section in ApplicationSettings.config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating an MVC application, then generally you can access your configuration file (web.config, in the root of the project) using ConfigurationManager:

```
string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServer"].ConnectionString;
```

You could try loading a different configuration file using:

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()
```

Here's a link to the MSDN documentation for the ConfigurationManager class:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx - specifically, there's some information included there about the class's intended usage and operation.

Hope that helps,

Cheers!

Comment: what if i am in a different project ?

Comment: If you're in a Windows Forms project, ConfigurationManager will read from app.config, located in the root of your project.

Comment: how can I specify a new appsetting in the web.configfile?

Comment: ConfigurationManager provides a read only view of whichever config file that you're using. If you're building a Windows Forms project, you might want to look at storing values inside the Properties objects.

To add new entries into the config file, you'll need to modify the configuration file directly.

I've edited my post to add links to the MSDN documentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your projets look like I'm going to go out on a limb here.

Just an FYI, in IIS there will be inheritance that may solve your issues, just be sure to setup your apps for debugging in IIS in the same folder structure.

If you have multiple libraries, you dont need config files for those libs (app.config), so what are you trying to to do eliminate multiple config files? Do you have multiple web sites? If you only have a single site and other class library projects, you won't beed other config files as they won't be used at runtime anyways. If you have multiple web sites, then consider inheritance.

[10 things asp.net developers should know about web.config inheritance and overrides](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx)